# Running join on Maybe Relation

Tags: database, haskell, yesod, persistent, esqueleto

I have a model

```
Assignment
   blah Text
   ....
```

and a model

```
File
    assignmentId AssignmentId Maybe
    ...
```

and I want to get all the files associated with an assignment in a join query. I have tried Esqueleto and `runJoin` with `selectOneMany` but haven't had any luck, so I am considering not using a join, or using rawSql. That really doesn't seem like a good idea, but I can't figure this out. Is there any support for that feature?

Comment: You should probably include the esqueleto and runJoin code you tried, together with the error messages you got.

Comment: Updated: example that compiles below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update, working example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE PackageImports, OverloadedStrings, ConstraintKinds #-}
module Handler.HTest where

import Import
import "esqueleto" Database.Esqueleto as Esql
import "monad-logger" Control.Monad.Logger (MonadLogger)
import "resourcet" Control.Monad.Trans.Resource (MonadResourceBase)
import qualified Data.List as L

getFilesByAssignment :: (PersistQuery (SqlPersist m), MonadLogger m
                                                  , MonadResourceBase m) =>
                        Text -> SqlPersist m [Entity File]
getFilesByAssignment myAssign = do
  result <- select $
        from $ \(assign `InnerJoin` file) -> do
          on (just (assign ^. AssignmentId)
            Esql.==. file ^. FileAssignmentId)
          where_ (assign ^. AssignmentBlah Esql.==. val myAssign)
          return (assign, file)

  return $ map snd (result :: [(Entity Assignment, Entity File)])

(.$) = flip ($)

getTestR :: Handler RepHtml
getTestR = do
       entFiles <- runDB $ getFilesByAssignment "test"
       defaultLayout $ do
               setTitle "Test page"
               entFiles .$ map (show . unKey . entityKey)
                        .$ L.intercalate ", "
                        .$ toHtml
                        .$ toWidget
```

Comment: I gave up and used rawSql, but I'll definitely refer back to this in the future. Thanks.